# Confused by freetype versions (pkg-config)

Tags: linux

I have freetype2 installed on my system but I am also trying to install it from source, as well.

My installed version is here: `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc`. That file is listed as version `20.0.14`.

To compile another tool, namely [fontconfig](https://fontconfig.org), I need `freetype2 >= 21.0.15`.

So I downloaded freetype2 [from its source git repo](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/freetype/freetype2.git).

The trouble I'm having is that repository doesn't list any version even close to 21.0.15+. All of the tags in that repository are listed as `VER-2-6-2`, `VER-2-9`, `VER-2-9-1`, etc. And the generated `freetype.pc` file which is created after compilation are also listed as `2.6.2`, `2.9`, `2.9.1`, etc. The version number is not `21.0.15` or even `20.0.14`, which my CentOS 7.6 already has.

What determines the listed version in the freetype.pc file? Where can I find the version of freetype that will create a .pc file of `>= 21.0.15+`? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the reason is because I was building freetype using CMake. And in the CMakeLists.txt, it's defining a version based on the version of freetype.

```
# . `CMakeLists.txt' is provided as-is since it is normally not used by the
#   developer team.
```

So it's unsupported. That's why the version number doesn't match.

In reality, the version number actually comes from libtool. See [this table](https://fossies.org/diffs/freetype/2.9.1_vs_2.10.0/docs/VERSIONS.TXT-diff.html). e.g. I was building 2.10.0 freetype, so the freetype.pc should have been written with a version of `23.0.17`

And if you build using configure, instead of cmake, you can find that exact same version 23.0.17 listed as "23:0:17" in the `builds/unix/configure.raw` file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is more complicated than this. There are two distinct versioning schemes used by the freetype project that are explained here:

https://github.com/freetype/freetype/blob/master/docs/VERSIONS.TXT

A `pkg-config` that reports `2.x` means that freetype hasn't been correctly compiled and installed. It is supposed to report `20.x`.